# Objective-C, mixing NSString with calculations and numbers in NSArray not allowed?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have two arrays winDscr and winSize. winDscr holds the descriptions and winSize is supposed to hold the values for the requested windows bounds. See below.

winDscr is OK so far. winSize however shows an error (Expected expression) at the 2. line containing '{2560,4*2560/5},'. I haven´t done it before this way, is it not allowed to mix NSString and calculations at all? What am I doing wrong?

Any clues would be very helpful, Tia, Ronald.

```
NSArray *winDscr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   @"Auto",
                   @"2560-> 5:4",
                   @"2560->16:10",
                   @"2048-> 4:3",
                   @"1920-> 4:3",
                   @"1920->16:10",
                   @"A2 Portrait",
                   @"A2 Landscape",
                   @"A3 Portrait",
                   @"A3 Landscape",
                   nil];

NSArray *winSize = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   @"Auto",
                   {2560,4*2560/5},
                   {2560,10*1920/16},
                   {2048,3*2048/4},
                   {1920,3*1920/4},
                   {1920,10*1920/16},
                   {[convertMMToPixel:420],[convertMMToPixel:594]},
                   {[convertMMToPixel:594],[convertMMToPixel:420]},
                   {[convertMMToPixel:297],[convertMMToPixel:420]},
                   {[convertMMToPixel:420],[convertMMToPixel:297]},
                   nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

First, `{2560,4*2560/5}` by itself is not a valid expression.  You can make it a literal `NSSize` expression by writing `(NSSize){2560,4*2560/5}`.  You can also write `NSMakeSize(2560, 4*2560/5)`, which uses a library function.

Second, an `NSArray` can only hold Objective-C objects, and a `NSSize` is not an Objective-C object.  You can wrap the `NSSize` in an `NSValue` and store the wrapper in the array:

```
NSArray *winSize = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   @"Auto",
                   [NSValue valueWithSize:(NSSize){2560,4*2560/5}],
                   [NSValue valueWithSize:(NSSize){2560,10*1920/16}],
                   ...
```

To extract a size:

```
NSValue *wrapper = winSize[2];
NSSize size = [wrapper sizeValue];
```

Comment: That´s what I thought, my fault :) And how about the curly brackets, are they allowed in this context?

Comment: I discussed the curly braces in the paragraph that starts with “First”.

Comment: Yes, of course, however valueWithCGSize was not accepted so I changed it to valueWithSize which works fine. Thanks a lot. And I changed '[convertMMToPixel:297]' to '[self convertMMToPixel:297]'. Thank you.

Comment: Just one more point. I tried several things to retrieve the values from winSize array like this:     
    NSInteger theIdx = [sender indexOfSelectedItem];    
    NSValue *theValues =  winSizeDimensions[theIdx];

which doesn´t throw an error. But how do I get the values? When I NSLog my winSize I get something like this which looks like text:
    "NSSize: {2560, 1440}",
    "NSSize: {2560, 2048}",
    "NSSize: {2560, 1200}",
    "NSSize: {2048, 1536}",

But how do I get the values???

Comment: Works like a charm :)) Thanks to all for great help.

Answer (score 0):

`{2560,4*2560/5}` is a C struct with two members, not an objective-C object. NSArrays can only hold objects. You'd need to hold these values inside an NSValue holding a CGSize (`valueWithCGSize:`) before trying to add them to the array.

Example:

```
...arrayWithObjects:
    @"Auto",
    [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(2560,4*2560/5)],
    ...
```

Comment: Ah, I understand, however valueWithCGSize was not accepted so I changed it to valueWithSize, is that still correct?

Comment: Could I use a C struct instead of NSArray for this purpose?

Comment: Oh, are you on OS X ? I assumed iOS. In that case, yes, and it should be NSSizeMake as well.

Comment: @jrturton Since `NSSize` is a typedef for `CGSize` on 64-bit, either may work, depending on the project.

Comment: An array is the best structure; an alternative would be a dictionary with the names as keys and sizes as values, but it depends what you're doing with the data later.

Comment: @robmayoff true, but I like to keep code in line with the docs - so if it says it accepts an NSSize, I'd rather explicitly give it one.

Comment: Sorry I didn´t mention that I´m on OSX. Yes, I was also thinking of nsdictionary but haven´t figure out yet how to do it. May be next try.